# Can we use Records in C# 8.0?

Tags: c#, record, c#-8.0, c#-9.0

I have a project using .NET Standard 2.1 and .NET core 3.1 - so the C# version is 8.0

According to a few articles I found (e.g. [one](https://blog.cdemi.io/whats-coming-in-c-8-0-records/), [two](http://www.devsanon.com/c/c-8-is-introducing-records/)), it should be possible to define a `record` type using this syntax:

```
public class MyRecord(string Input1, int Input2);
```

But I get many compilation errors, as this syntax for defining a class is clearly incorrect.

Are these articles misleading?

Is the only way to use records to upgrade to C# 9.0, and therefore .NET 5.0?

Comment: `public record` and not `public class`

Comment: changing it to `record` gives `Predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit' is not defined or imported` - it seems to be a feature of c# 9

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record - first sentence `Beginning with C# 9...`

Comment: @RandRandom Yes, the question is whether the articles which claim that its possible in c# 8 are incorrect

Comment: Yes, they're incorrect - but reasonably so, given that the first states: "Again, before I go any further, I would like to point out that as I'm writing this, the feature-set for C# 8.0 still hasn't been decided. This means that information written here is subject to change." and the second states: "Just to be clear, this was initially planned for C# version 8 but due to other more important features and the complexity of this feature it has been postponed for a point version with unclear path if it will be in 8.1 or 8.2 etc"

Comment: But also, see https://btburnett.com/csharp/2020/12/11/csharp-9-records-and-init-only-setters-without-dotnet5.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I have a project using .NET Standard 2.1 and .NET core 3.1 - so the C# version is 8.0

Incorrect. The *default* C# version is 8.0, but you can use *any language version you like* (as long as you have the correct build tools and build SDK), simply by changing the language version. The easiest way to do this is in the csproj:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

There are some caveats:

1. some features require additional type definitions which will be missing on earlier frameworks, but can be added manually or via additional nuget package references; in the case of records, this may require `IsExternalInit`, which PMF shows you how to define, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67687186/23354)
2. some features require *runtime* features, and **can not work** on earlier frameworks, such as the new default interface implementation feature
3. you [*won't get any support from Microsoft*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) - if it works, great; if it doesn't; meh

> Is the only way to use records to upgrade to C# 9.0, and therefore .NET 5.0?

No; you need the .NET 5 build SDK, but you can still target .NET Core 3.1 etc.

Answer (score 13):

To avoid the error `Predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit' is not defined or imported`, just add the following code anywhere in your project:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Reserved to be used by the compiler for tracking metadata.
    /// This class should not be used by developers in source code.
    /// This dummy class is required to compile records when targeting .NET Standard
    /// </summary>
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public static class IsExternalInit
    {
    }
}
```

Then the record types should be `netstandard2.0`-compliant, meaning they work also under i.e. .NET 4.8.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the other 2 answers I now understand the problem I am having

My csproj contains this line

```
<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
```

So I am using C# 9.0, and in fact I am able to use the `record` keyword like this

```
public record MyRecord
{
    public string Input1 { get; set; }
    public int Input2 { get; set; }
}
```

But if I want to use the more concise syntax from my question, I would need to include `IsExternalInit` from [PMF's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67687186)

In fact that would let me define it as

```
public sealed record MyRecord(string Input1, int Input2);
```

Also worth noting Jon Skeet's comment that this may eventually be released to some version of 8.X